# Visual sourcesafe tree view is not synchronize with the root folder?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I'm using microsoft visual sourcesafe 2005.

I set the database folder is D:\Code

When I merge code and check in the new code in to source safe. I assume that the file that I has just checked in is $\Code\a.cpp. But when I open the file a.cpp on folder D:\Code\a.cpp, I don't see the new lines code checked in. It always is the old version of files.

Is that VSS's bug?

Thank you!

T&TGroup

Comment: What's your VSS version? Check out the update here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943847

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you can provide more information.

1. How did you merge the files? Please make sure that you merged the modification to $\Code\a.cpp, not the opposite.
2. Please check the history of a.cpp and learn the actions you've done on the file. Do the diff operation on the historic versions if necessary.
3. Instead of opening the local file, did you try opening a.cpp directly from VSS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
1. I check out a.cpp and browser it to another folder (Checkout folder), and I edit this file and then I check in back in to VSS.
2,3: After check in, I can see the newest update of this file on VSS and previous versions. But on the database folder (D:\Code) that I have selected when create database with this project is not update.

Comment: The working folder and check out folder can be different. For instance, you set the working folder D:\Code for $\Code. You can still check out a.cpp to C:\Code for example. After you check in the file, the latest version on your local machine is in C:\Code, not in D:\Code. Hope the information helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confused with the "working folder" concept. Say, you set D:\Code as the working folder of $/, and the solution/project which contains a.cpp is in another folder, say, E:\Code.

Now, if you edit a.cpp in Visual Studio and then check in, "E:\Code\a.cpp" is updated, but not "D:\Code\a.app".

Comment: Thank you!
I will explain for more detail: The D:\Code is a folder that I select when create the database to connect with VSS. Then I check out file a.cpp to "Checkout" folder, edit this file and then check in back to VSS. After that, on VSS I see the file a.cpp has updated with last version and when I show history i can see previous versions. But I don't know why the root "database folder" D:\Code\a.cpp is not updated.